# Help understanding divisibility proofs

Tags: discrete-mathematics, divisibility

Can someone please explain how to do this problem?

> Prove or disprove the statement “If $a \mid b$ and $c \mid d$, then $(a + c)\mid(b + d)$”.

Comment: Experimentation with such things can be very important, both in a search for a counterexample and a search for a proof. In your case, in seconds you will find a counerexample.

Answer (score 3):

Take $a=2,b=4,c=3,d=3$, then what can you say ?

Comment: This is funny ^^

Comment: Yes, counter examples are easy to find, but how do I write the proof for one that is true? I can't possibly test every example. Like this one: Prove or disprove the statement “If a | c and b | d, then ab | cd”.

Comment: Assume $a \mid c$ and $b \mid d$.  Then there exist integers $l,m$ with $am = c$ and $bl = d$.  Find integer $q$ with $(ab)*q=cd$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\ $ By the [mediant inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/205667/242) $\rm\:\frac{b}a < \frac{d}c\:\Rightarrow\:\frac{b}{a} < \frac{b+d}{a+c} < \frac{d}{c}.\:$  Therefore, when the extreme terms are consecutive integers, the middle term is not an integer.