# Prove that if a fraction is broken up into two the resulting two fractions cannot both have a larger value

Tags: probability, inequality, ratio

I am working on research involving probability tables. I simplified the problem to the following. Say we have the following:

$C_1, C_2, C_3, C_4$

$\forall i, C_i > 0$

$x = \frac{C_1 + C_2}{C_1 + C_2 + C_3 + C_4}$

$y = \frac{C_1}{C_1 + C_3}$

$z = \frac{C_2}{C_2 + C_4}$

I am almost positive (by just filling in numbers) that *both* $y$ and $z$ cannot $> x$ or $< x$. Meaning that unless $y = z$, then either $y < x$ and $z > x$ or $y > x$ and $z < x$. Does anyone have suggestions for an approach to prove this?

==EDIT==
Basically, I am trying to prove that either of these two situations are impossible:

$z \geq y > x$

$x > y \geq z$

Answer (score 1):

The number $x$ defined in this way is called the mediant of the two numbers
$y$ and $z$ defined in this way.
It is known that the mediant of two distinct numbers is strictly between those numbers.
See [this question and its answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/205654/given-4-integers-a-b-c-d-0-does-fracab-fraccd-imply-fra).

(This answer replaces my previous answer completely, as that answer was based on a slight misformatting of the question, which has since been corrected.)

Comment: I'm not quite sure I follow, in that example $x=\frac{4}{7}$, $y=\frac{2}{4}$ and $z=\frac{2}{3}$. In that case, $z > x > y$, which is what I believe to hold true. I am trying to prove that it is impossible for $x > z \geq y$ or $z > y \geq x$

Comment: Sorry about the unclear formatting - just fixed it!

Comment: OK, fixed the answer to correspond this time (I hope) to the question you meant to ask!

Comment: Great thanks - would like to vote your answer up but I don't have enough reputation =T

Comment: That's OK, I decided I don't need any more credit for this since all I really did in the end was remember I'd seen a question about the mediant before, which enabled me to look up someone else's answer. Glad to help, anyway.