# An inequality involving fractions and a minimum

Tags: inequality, reference-request, fractions

It can be proved easily by contradiction that

> if $a,b,c,d$ are positive numbers, then
>   $$\frac{a+b}{c+d} \geq \min\Big\{ \frac{a}{c},\frac{b}{d}\Big\}.$$

I am *not* looking for a proof but rather for
1) a reference or book which contain this and similar inequalities;
2) information whether this inequality can be sharpened.

Thanks!

Comment: since $1=\dfrac{\epsilon+n}{n+\epsilon}$ gives a min in $\dfrac{\epsilon}n$ it probably can be sharpened by considering $a\ge b$  and $c\ge d$, this has to be verified.

Comment: you want a reference but where did you take it from?

Comment: Compare https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/205654/given-4-integers-a-b-c-d-0-does-fracab-fraccd-imply-fra, where this is interpreted as the [mediant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediant_%28mathematics%29), or as a slope in a parallelogram.

Comment: @MartinR wow, thanks a lot! Please consider putting this down as the answer which it really is!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{a+b}{c+d}$$ is the “mediant” of the fractions $\frac ac$ and 
$\frac bd$  – more precisely, the mediant of the ordered pairs $(a, c)$
and $(b, d)$. Your observation is the “mediant inequality”:
If $a, b, c, d > 0$ then
$$
 \frac ac < \frac bd \quad \Longrightarrow \quad 
 \frac ac < \frac{a+b}{c+d} < \frac bd \, .
$$
This and more properties and applications of the mediant
are described in
 [Wikipedia: Mediant (mathematics)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediant_%28mathematics%29).

The mediant can also be interpreted geometrically as the slope of the diagonal in a parallelogram, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/205667/42969).

Answer (score 0):

Let $\frac{b}{d}\geq\frac{a}{c}$.

Hence, we need to prove vthat
$$\frac{a+b}{c+d}\geq\frac{a}{c}$$ or
$$ac+bc\geq ac+ad$$or
$$bc\geq ad,$$ which is our assuming.

By the same way we can check the case $\frac{b}{d}\leq\frac{a}{c}$.

Comment: Thanks very much, but as I wrote, I am really after a reference or whether this can be sharpened.