# Given a sequence of bounded fractions, what the range of the sum of their numerators divided by the sum of their denominators?

Tags: analysis, inequality, fractions

If 
$$
\frac{b_1}{a_1}, \frac{b_2}{a_2}, \dots, \frac{b_n}{a_n}
$$
lies within $[\alpha, \beta]$, does $\frac{\sum_{i=1}^nb_i}{\sum_{i=1}^na_i}$ lies within the same range? (Given that $\sum_{i=1}^na_i \neq 0$.) If the answer is no, what about the situation that $a_n\gt 0$?

Comment: This is hard to read.  [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a tutorial on formatting for this site.

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/205654/42969